# Is it possible to change image folder in cakephp 2.4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have read many docs, but failed to solve the problem:
Images in my existing project stored in `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/media/'`
I want, but can't change in cakephp 2.4 default image folder from `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/webroot/img/'` to any I desire.

lib/Cake/bootstrap.php contains constants:

```
/**
 * Path to the public images directory.
 */
if (!defined('IMAGES')) {
    define('IMAGES', WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS);
}

/**
 * Web path to the public images directory.
 */
if (!defined('IMAGES_URL')) {
    define('IMAGES_URL', 'img/');
}
```

and

```
Configure::write('App.imageBaseUrl', IMAGES_URL);
```

I tried to change:

```
IMAGES to $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/media/'

IMAGES_URL to /
```

And it doesn't work at all. All image files still points to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/webroot/img/'` I see it when try to render image in view:

```
echo $this->Html->image('/img/ride_scheme/chema.jpg', array( 'width' => 300 ));
```

If I created `in app/webroot/img/ride_scheme`  image file *chema.jpg*  it rendered, but I changed the folder in IMAGES constant in **lib/Cake/bootstrap.php** !!!

In documentation I see:

> Constants IMAGES_URL, JS_URL, CSS_URL have been deprecated and
>   replaced with config vari- ables App.imageBaseUrl, App.jsBaseUrl,
>   App.cssBaseUrl respectively.
>   Constants IMAGES, JS, CSS have been deprecated.

I gues that is the problem.

Please, show me how to change image folder

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I reckon `IMAGES_URL` should be `media/` and not just `/`.

Alternatively, you could add a RewriteRule to your `.htaccess` (in the project root) to rewrite everything to the media folder (assuming you have an Apache web server with the Rewrite module enabled):

```
RewriteRule ^app/webroot/img/(.*) /media/$1
```

Or you could create a symbolic link that links the img/ folder to your media folder (assuming you're on Linux hosting and you have ssh/shell access to your server):

```
cd app/webroot
rm -rf img/
ln -s ../../media img
```